# My WOT api not working in the chrome extension iam developing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on an google chrome extension to submit for my academic project, like an Adblocker.

So in my extension whenever you click an external link it checks whether its an advertisement or not ,if its an advertisement it displays an alert ,and **in the alert part i wanted to show the 
My Wot rating,** for that purpose i have secured the *API key* and i have been trying for the past few days to display so.

So whenever i call the MY WOT api link that is

http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json?hosts=http://mathrubhumi.com/&callback=process&key=e4ae59175895506dde09ee2ce355f3a19797e445

it displays the result as:

process({ "mathrubhumi.com": { "target": "mathrubhumi.com", "0": [ 86, 38 ], "1": [ 86, 38 ], "2": [ 86, 38 ], "4": [ 84, 37 ] } } )

but whenever i try to call the api via my extension it says undefined.

This is the Java Script code I have been trying:

```
// click safe coded      
var data;

var url = window.location.href;
if (!url.substring(0, 3) == "www" || !url.substring(0, 3) == "htt" || url.indexOf('ads') > 0)
{


   getJSON('http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json?hosts=http://mathrubhumi.com/&callback=process&key=e4ae59175895506dde09ee2ce355f3a19797e445'), then(function (data) {


//   alert('Your Site has Trust Score result of:  ' + data.result); 

  result.innerText = data.result;
```

.
    });

Thanks.

Comment: That code should be inside a [background/event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and the API url whitelisted in [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions). Also `location.href` never starts with `www`, always with a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to append some details for @wOxxOm's exactly comments:

1. [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). Basically if you send ajax from content scripts, it would be limited by [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). While extensions are not limited by this, as long as you request cross-origin permissions. See above link for what you would need to add.
2. After moving the ajax logic from content scripts to background page, if you need to transfer data between these two pages (they're living in two different contexts), you would want to take a look at [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) part.
3. For the [`Window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object, see this link and you will find `Location.href` contains the entire URL, so protocol is needed.